# Degree of minimal polynomial when number of distinct eigenvalues are given

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

If a square matrix of order $ 10 $ has exactly $ 4 $ distinct eigenvalues, then degree of it's minimal polynomial is

1. At least $ 4 $
2. At most $ 4 $
3. At least $ 6 $
4. At most $ 6 $

$ 4 $ distinct eigenvalues would mean $ 4 $ factors in the minimal polynomial: $ ( x - a ) ( x - b ) ( x - c ) ( x - d ) $, where $ a $, $ b $, $ c $ and $ d $ are the distinct eigenvalues, but I can't see how the minimal polynomial can have degree more than or less than $ 4 $.

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could answer any of the following: where did you encounter this problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Apologies, didn't know the standard procedures for asking a question. Thank you for informing, I have edited the question

Comment: Great, hopefully your question will be reopened. In the mean time: if the minimal polynomial has $4$ distinct factors, then the degree of the polynomial is at least $4$. That's why 1 is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roots of the minimal polynomial are precisely the eigenvalues, and the degree of a nonzero polynomial is at least the number of its roots, so 1. is true.

With your conditions, it is possible for the minimal polynomial to have any degree between 4 (in the diagonalisable case) and 10, so all the other answers are false.

To prove this, let's call $J_k = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \in M_k(\mathbb C)$ the usual nilpotent Jordan block.

You can easily check that the minimal polynomial of $J_k$ is $X^k$.

For $1 \leq k \leq 7$, the block-diagonal matrix $\mathrm{diag}(1,2,3) \oplus J_k \oplus \mathrm{diag}(\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{\text{$7-k$ zeroes}}) \in M_{10}(\mathbb C)$ has four eigenvalues, and its minimal polynomial is $X^k(X-1)(X-2)(X-3)$.

Comment: So if our matrix was specifically mentioned to be non-nilpotent, then we would have exactly 4 as the degree of the polynomial. Am I right?

Comment: Your matrix cannot be nilpotent, because it has nonzero eigenvalues (at least three of them). The minimal polynomial degree would be $4$ if and only if the matrix is diagonalisable.

Comment: Yea yea, I confused myself with the example of the nilpotent Jordan block you mentioned. Nilpotent matrices have only zero as eigenvalue. So yea, I think you've cleared all the confusion I had regarding this topic.